# How to change button cursor to hand?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm using this code to create button:

```
var button = game.add.button(0, 0, "background", this.buttonClick, this, 2, 1, 0);
```

After creation button has cursor hand.
After that in the middle I need to disable button so I add this line:

```
button.input.enabled = false;
```

And on the end to enable again button I add this line:

```
button.input.enabled = true;
```

Button is here enabled and I can click on it but cursor is pointer, not hand.

Tried to solve with this line but without success:

```
button.useHandCursor = true;
```

How to solve that?

Comment: have you already tried button.input.useHandCursor = true; ?

Comment: I realized now that I had to use: button.input.useHandCursor = true; instead of button.useHandCursor = true; Should I delete me question?

Comment: It may be worth answering it yourself, this seems like the sort of thing that could be a useful resource to others, even if the solution for you was just a small change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized now that I had to use:

```
button.input.useHandCursor = true;
```

instead of

```
button.useHandCursor = true;
```